# Swift 4.2 error: use of unimplemented initializer 'init()' for class

Tags: hash, xcode10, swift4.2

I have a class like this:

```
class SomeRequest: Hashable {
    let parameter: String

    init(parameter: String) {
        self.parameter = parameter
    }

    var hashValue: Int {
        return parameter.hashValue
    }
}
```

Than I try to set value to dictionary by key, where key is SomeRequest:

```
let request = SomeRequest(parameter: "Some")
let dictionary: [SomeRequest: Any] = [:]
dictionary[request] = ...
```

After all this I get this error: "*use of unimplemented initializer 'init()' for class*"

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift 4.2 has changed the protocol **Hashable**. You can see new func:

```
public func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher)
```

The reason of crash, that hash(into: ) call SomeRequest.init().
You can say: *Hey, i don't adopt hash(into: ) method!* But swift does behind the scene.

For fix that you need implement hash(into:) :

```
class SomeRequest: Hashable {
let parameter: String

init(parameter: String) {
    self.parameter = parameter
}

func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
    hasher.combine(self.parameter)
}
}
```

Now, you can remove *vashValue*. It's calculated by hash(into:) automatically.

Answer (score 2):

In details you can figure out what's new in Hashable here:
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/115/swift-4-2-improves-hashable-with-a-new-hasher-struct